# Android:ViewPager - PagerSlidingTabStrip, Custom Tab Background on state_selected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I need to use a custom background for each tab when each one of them is in *state_selected* mode. But still nothing happens when I select a tab.

I used selector like this: (*tab_selector.xml*)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_tab" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

And this is the *activity_main.xml*:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_back"
    app1:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app1:pstsIndicatorColor="#00FFFFFF"
    app1:pstsShouldExpand="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

As obvious I'm using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) by astuetz.
And here is how I'm using ViewPager and PagerSlidingTabStrip:

```
final PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(mainPagerAdapter);
tabs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

I tried mixing different states and re-positioning them, but still not working.
I tried to put an specific tab on a selected mode but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself, but not in a standard way!
Since I needed a gradient like background on my selected tab, I used indicator and underline like this:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_back"
    app1:pstsUnderlineHeight="24dip"
    app1:pstsIndicatorHeight="48dip"
    app1:pstsIndicatorColor="#e7e7e7"
    app1:pstsShouldExpand="true" />
```

Comment: Hey,I want to do the same but don't understand what is app1 ??

Comment: You can use this to customize the properties of this library. I used this many weeks ago, but I think to have more than one element, you should use app2, app3, and so forth. [PagerSlidingTabStrip-Customization](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip#customization)

Comment: @FarzadDev, do you know how to put a different drawable into each tab? The `xml` customization `pstsTabBackground` for using a tab selector file will only use one image. Can't figure out how to get 4 different drawables to go on my 4 tabs. Thanks if you know.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who are looking for the answer without using the forked PageSliding tab Strip.

For The selector problem, you can set OnPageChangeListener on the tabStrip with a CustomOnPageChangeListener, and set selected_state of the button inside tabStrip to "true"

Here is my CustomOnPageChangeListener

```
private class CustomOnPageChangeListenner implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip;
    private int previousPage=0;
    //Constructor initiate with TapStrip
    //
    public CustomOnPageChangeListenner(PagerSlidingTabStrip tab){
        tabStrip=tab;
        //Set the first image button in tabStrip to selected,
        ((LinearLayout)tabStrip.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setSelected(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        //set the previous selected page to state_selected = false
        ((LinearLayout)tabStrip.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(previousPage).setSelected(false);
        //set the selected page to state_selected = true
        ((LinearLayout)tabStrip.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i).setSelected(true);
        //remember the current page
        previousPage=i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

    }
}
```

And then you set this custom listener to your tab strip

```
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip;
tabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomOnPageChangeListenner(tabStrip));
```

Comment: Your snipped does not work bro. NPE in  ((LinearLayout)tabStrip.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)

Answer (score 1):

I call `PagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener`
and not `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener`

It works for me.